# Will Window RT have a JVM?

Tags: windows-8, java, windows-rt

Java is supposed to be a way to write portable programs, and one person we work with wrote some of our buisness applications in Java. Doing some prelimiary compatibility checking and it seems that there currently isn't a JVM for Windows on the arm platform.

Are there any plans for the Apache or OpenJDK JVM to run on Windows 8 RT? Will devices like the Surface never run Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have read on various other sites, including Stackoverflow, the answer is likely to be No.

This is because Windows 8 has been deliberately designed that way.

Some links that elaborate more on this are listed here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfwinrt-surfnetwork/is-java-available-on-windows-rt/580222f0-3095-438c-b9d9-0fb07c4167fa?msgId=abb04c26-9c7d-4865-a74b-988b42868f9b

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/fb054992-c8f8-492b-b292-6a417c351383/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041389/compile-and-run-a-external-java-program-in-winrt

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942178/running-java-swing-application-on-windows-8-tablet

Answer (score 1):

Just to help clear up Mamta's answer, Windows RT may not necessarily support Java.

Windows 8 PRO definately supports Java.  This is the standard version of Windows that you are familiar with and is very similar to Windows 7.

Microsoft Surface comes in 2 flavors - RT and PRO.

So Surface RT may not support Java.  Surface PRO does support java.  The PRO version of the Surface simply is not out yet but you have plenty of other tablet and laptop options already that do support Windows 8 PRO.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it and I didn't research much so I don't know if it can be useful but there is JVM implementation written in .NET ([IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/)). This JVM is listed on list of applications that run on jailbroken WinRT ([forum.xda-developers.com](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092348)). On this forum they say about IKVM.NET this:

> IKVM. Java, implemented in .NET (can run many pure-Java apps)